# IP Monitoring To Check Uptime or Down

Tags: monitoring

What tools do you use to check if your host/devices on your network are online in one glance. i have multiple companies with APs, servers and NAS. Of course I can ping one by one, but I'm sure you have a better one. I heard Nagios Core seem the solution, but it hell of overkill features.

Same question here asked by https://serverfault.com/questions/785045/monitoring-if-the-ip-is-down-not-up but yet to be answered.

Newbie here.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: This question has a very large number of answers, both commercial and non commercial and many will be largely opinion based rather than fact. Please consider adding more information as to your specific requirements as opposed to just `I want to monitor stuff`.

Comment: Just simple tool, I'm about think to coding myself given by static IP, ping to host, if the host alive, return value good = display green indicator. Something like that. Extra feature, I can access it thru remotely.

Answer (score 0):

for a simple set-up and easy to use and customise I would recommend Zabbix http://www.zabbix.com/ it also do have a lot of feature that you can use on different use-case, Nagios is also a very great tool the only thing I heard complaint about Nagios is the initial set-up and configuration

Comment: Thank you, Zabbit seem good solution. Gonna setup it on my VM first. Thank you once again.

Comment: no problem. cheers! :)